# OpenSSH Windows server 2012 : SCP process randomally working : with passowrd authentication

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, scp, public-key

I have created a openSSH SCP bat script and scheduled task to run as `SYSTEM`. I use publickkey authentication method. For that converted a private key of winscp to openSSH key using putty key gen and set permission of private key file read access only for `SYSTEM` user and changed file owner too.

So when task runs it succesfully connects and works fine but sometimes its getting stuck without any error and task scheduler stuck i nrunning state.

In logs, it shows

```
debug1: AUthentications that can continue :publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next Authentication method : publickkey
debug1:Trying private key:d:/apps/keys/prvikey
debug1: AUthentications that can continue :publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next Authentication method : keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase:can't open /dev/tty:No such file or directory
```

After that if i go and end task scheduler process and kill any cmd.exe waiting for scp.exe PID and run again it works sometimes and failes sometimes.

Windows OS: Windows server 2012

Command used:

```
scp -v -i D:\apps\keys\prvikey D:\apps\file* user1@sftp.com:\ftp\rcvfile\
```

Comment: i found that with scp-vvv option , when the connectiion fail i see the return packet type is 51 but succesfull case return npacket type is 52
when authentication fails :


*
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent publickkey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet : type 51
debug1: AUthentications that can continue :publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive*